# How many elements are there in S whose digits add up to 9?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following set

$$S = \{x \in Z|1 \le x \le 10010\}$$.

How many elements are there in S whose digits add up to $9$?

For example $8001$ is an element of $S$ whose digits add up to $9$.

Can someone please tell me the answer to this question and explain it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Sum of digits of multiple of $9$ is a multiple of $9$ itself.

$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=9$

Number of possible values, such that $0 \le a_i \le 9$. $a_1 \neq 0$.

$a_1=1$, then $a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=8 \implies$, number of solutions is : $8-1 \choose 5-1$

$a_1=2$, then $a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=7 \implies$, number of solutions is : $7-1 \choose 5-1$

$a_1=3$, then $a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=8 \implies$, number of solutions is : $6-1 \choose 5-1$

And so on. Careful counting will give you a right answer. This is a standard [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you just said? I don't get it. Thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer. Have a look. Hope you get it now.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now.Thanks again!

Comment: Hi inceptio, I was wondering if you can explain a tiny bit more. Because if you keep going on with the pattern you eventual get c(3,4) or (c2,4) which is zero.